# C++ Comparing strings to determine palindrome

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to determine if a string is a palindrome by reversing the string and then comparing the letters of both strings. The code is provided underneath. So far whatever I put I always get "is a palindrome " as an output. I am aware of the short cut method for doing this easily and efficiently but trying to understand the long way as well. I am using C++ 11

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string reversed = " ";

void reverse_sentence(string s)
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++)
    {
        reversed = s[i] + reversed;
        
    }
    cout << reversed;
    
}

void is_pal(string reversed, string s)
{
    int flag = 0;
    
    // if(s == string(s.rbegin(), s.rend())){
    //   cout << "is a palindrome"<<endl;
    
    // }else{
    //   cout <<"failed"<<endl;
    
    // }
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= reversed.length(); j++)
        {
            if (s[i] != reversed[j - 1])
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
            
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        cout << "is palindrome" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "not palindrome" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s = "hello";
    reverse_sentence(s);
    is_pal(s, reversed);
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: There are lots of issues with your code. Turn on all warnings, and fix all of them. Remove `using namespace std;`. Remove the global non-const variable `reversed`. That'll fix a lot of bugs.

Comment: Unrelated: No need to reverse. Compare the first and last characters. If they aren't the same, not a palindrome. Otherwise move in one character on both sides and compare. Keep moving toward the center until there's a mismatch or you reach the center. N/2 maximum compares instead of all of the swapping and then N compares.

Comment: If you have to reverse and compare, you may find `std::reverse` useful.

Comment: Side note: `<=` in a for loop's exit condition is usually a mistake. I recommend you look more closely at this to make sure it's not a mistake in your case.

Comment: If your encoding is UTF-8, and it's non-English (or not necessarily English), you may have more work to do to properly handle Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue...

your for loops go out of bounds...  length() gives you number of characters in the string.   Those characters have index 0 through length() - 1.  Because you are using <= s.length() however, then the last time through you get erroneous data, if it doesn't give you out of bounds error.  For loops using length() should be from i = 0 to i < s.length()

Biggest issue...

```
void is_pal(string reversed, string s)
{
    int flag = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= reversed.length(); j++)
        {
            if (s[i] != reversed[j - 1])
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
            
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        cout << "is palindrome" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "not palindrome" << endl;
    }
}
```

Your j loop is inside of your i loop.. which means that s[i] never changes as you compare it to every single value in reversed... unless every single character in reversed is the same character... then one of them is guaranteed to be not equal to s[i] which means that flag will be set to 1... which means your function reports it to be a palindrome...

Not only that.. but you already went through the process of doing the reverse... why are you trying to compare against reverse.. in reverse order?  That would be the same as comparing against the original string in normal order...

Assuming your reverse_sentence function works correctly... then s.length() is the same as reversed.length().  So to see if s is the same forwards as it is backwards then the letter at each index of s should be exactly the same as the letter at the same index in reversed.  Also what you are looking for is when they don't match... so you should initialize your flag to assume at the beginning that they are going to be matching and only set it to false when you discover that they don't match...

```
void is_pal(string reversed, string s)
{
    bool flag = true;

    // run loop through length of s or until we know s doesn't match reversed
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() && flag; i++) 
    {
        if (s[i] != reversed[i])
        {
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    
    if (flag)
    {
        cout << "is palindrome" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "not palindrome" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me. I realize now how dumb that code was.